# Physical access to ndk program built with gradle

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm looking for the information whether is it possible:

I have a program which can be execute on PC using **make root** and adb shell. What we can find in the makefile:

```
all: build

build:
    ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=./Android.mk APP_PLATFORM=android-21 

push: build
    adb push libs/armeabi/program /data/local/tmp/program
    adb push libs/armeabi/run-as /data/local/tmp/run-as

root: push  
    adb shell 'chmod 777 /data/local/tmp/run-as'
    adb shell '/data/local/tmp/program /system/bin/run-as /data/local/tmp/run-as'
    adb shell /system/bin/run-as

clean:
    rm -rf libs
    rm -rf obj
```

Of course module is added to gradle build:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path "src/nativeCode/test/Android.mk"
    }
}
productFlavors {
    arm7 {
        // in the future, ndk.abiFilter might also work
        ndk {
            abiFilter 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
    }
    arm8 {
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
        }
    }
    arm {
        ndk {
            abiFilter 'armeabi'
        }
    }
    x86 {
        ndk {
            abiFilter 'x86'
        }
    }
    x86_64 {
        ndk {
            abiFilter 'x86_64'
        }
    }
    mips {
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'mips', 'mips64'
        }
    }
    universal {
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'mips', 'mips64', 'x86', 'x86_64'
        }
    }
}
```

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
  program.c

LOCAL_MODULE := program
LOCAL_LDFLAGS   += -llog
LOCAL_CFLAGS    += -DDEBUG
LOCAL_CFLAGS    += -fPIE
LOCAL_LDFLAGS   += -fPIE -pie

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
  run-as.c

LOCAL_MODULE := run-as
LOCAL_CFLAGS    += -fPIE
LOCAL_LDFLAGS   += -fPIE -pie

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Problem is that i think I can't use JNI. I need a physical access (paths) to program and run-as to execute commands like in the makefile (pass path to run-as as an argument).

Comment: What is the reason of all these manipulations with `run-as` and what exactly is your `program` intended for?

Comment: i need that to test some vulnerabilities in android. implementation of these two programs is available here: https://github.com/Tlgyt/DirtyCowAndroid/tree/master/DirtyCow. program = dirtycow (only name changed)

Comment: Is the question still relevant, then?

Comment: Nope. I fixed typo. That's why its 'refreshed'